# Heroku NodeJS On Schedule (Run Once)

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, scheduler

I've prepared a NodeJS app in Heroku with the intent of running once daily with the "Heroku Scheduler" add-on. As much as I can tell, the scheduler is working as intended. The problem I'm experiencing is that the script will run, complete, and then repeat ad nauseam.

I have had to manually set my Node dynos to zero to "pause" it betwene jobs which sort of voids the intent of scheduling. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't stop the Heroku node app from running repeatedly, but I modified the scripts -> start in the "package.json" file to run nothing:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": ""
  }
```

This stopped the node app from wasting resources and now only launches when the scheduled task is initiated.